# Passing Parameter to JavaScript function from MVC Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor view that displays a number of photos. When a user clicks on a photo, I want that photo to display in a different box.

Display all photos (the photos display fine):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.CatalogItems)
                            {
                                <td><img src="../../Content/@item.ProductImageURL" onclick="changeImage('@item.Id')" border="0" data-toggle="tooltip" style="width:120px; height: 120px; border: 1px solid #444; vertical-align: bottom;" data-placement="top" title="@item.ProductDescription" /></td>
                            }
```

JavaScript to change a different photo to the selected photo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeImage(itemid) {
        document.getElementById("#empty-item1").innerHTML = "<img src='../../Content/@Model.CatalogItems[itemid].ProductImageURL' border='0'
    }
</script>
```

The error I'm getting on the JavaScript function is The name 'itemid' doesn't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `itemId` is a javascript variable. The C# expression `@Model.CatalogItems[itemid]` will be executed at server.

The razor view engine will execute the code inside your razor view and the output of that (Mostly HTML& JavaScript, which the browser can understand) will be send to the client(browser). Browser will then execute this response(parse HTML, JavaScript and execute it) on the client side. The `changeImage` method is a JavaScript method which gets executed on the browser when end user clicks on the image.  When razor executes the line `@Model.CatalogItems[itemid]` to produce the output, it does not have `itemId` variable defined/available, hence you are getting the error.

Instead of passing the `itemId`, you can pass the image path as it is.

```
onclick="changeImage('../../Content/@item.ProductImageURL')"
```

and in your `changeImage` method, use this value to update the other image src

```
function changeImage(src) {
    document.getElementById("#empty-item1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + src +"' />
}
```